# SQL optimization issues

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have to optimize a bunch of many table and data included SQL queries, and I would like to ask some questions:

1) There are situations, when the same functions are needed in different queries. Which results lower processor time: if the functions are calculated separately in every queries or if it is calculated in one query, and they are linked through each other?

2) When creating queries, which is better in giving table relationships? If I have 1 main query, and all of the other queries are related to that, or if there is a serial connection between all the tables?

The 2 main tables are relatively big (~30MB) Excel-tables.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand both questions. What is "linked through each other" and "a serial connection"? Please give simple examples of each option for both questions.

Comment: if you find yourself needing the exact same data in multiple queries (whether that data is generated by function or query) it is often more efficient to write that data to temp table first, then use the temp data for your following queries, then to continuously call a query a function over and over again.

Comment: as per the second question.  Would you be using inner joins or left joins?